# Rendering command object in gson

Tags: grails, gson, grails3

I'm using Grails 3 and `org.grails.plugins:views-json:1.0.0`. Is it possible to render command object as a json result? Is it rendering only domain classes provided in a model?

I tried:

```
model {
    TrainingStatisticsCommand cmd
}

json.cmd {
    startDate cmd?.startDate
    endDate cmd?.endDate
    trainings tmpl.training(cmd?.trainings)
}
```

but I received:

```
{
    "cmd": {
        "startDate": null,
        "endDate": null,
        "trainings": null
    }
}
```

I'm executing it from controller as:

```
    respond cmd, [status: OK, view:"trainingsByClients"]
```

and `cmd` object has inside some data for sure.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I guess, that the var inside the "json.cmd" closure should be "it" and not "cmd".

Comment: I tried it but then I received `No such property: startDate for class: java.lang.Object`, `No such property: endDate for class: java.lang.Object` and `No such property: trainings for class: java.lang.Object`.

Comment: Maybe you need to declare a var like `json.cmd { var -> var.startDate ... }`

Comment: I tried it but still `No such property` errors occur. I'm think that command object is not handled properly.

Comment: Try this with respond `respond cmd, view: 'trainingsByClients', status: OK`

Comment: No success: `Caused by: grails.views.ViewRenderException: Error rendering view: Cannot get property 'startDate' on null object` and then `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'startDate' on null object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You model would need to be

```
model {
   TrainingStatisticsCommand trainingStatisticsCommand
}
```

Or you would need to be explicit about the model variable name.

Comment: thx @Graeme Rocher. I used `render` instead of `respond` with explicit model like I mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41200464/redering-few-models-in-gson and it worked. However I'm stuck at custom gsons: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41231312/different-both-bad-output-for-render-and-respond (in that case both `render` and `respond` do not work).