# Different (both bad) output for render and respond custom gson

Tags: grails, gson, grails3

I'm using Grails 3.2.3 and created own views in **grails-app/views/training**:

in **_short-training.gson**

```
import com.example.trainings.Training

model {
    Training training
}

json g.render(training, [includes:['id', 'name']])
```

in **short-index.gson**

```
import com.example.trainings.Training

model {
    Iterable<Training> trainingList
}

json tmpl.'short-training'(trainingList ?: [])
```

in controller I tried two different approaches but noone of them is working. Both return 200 status but instead of 6 training instances I received:

```
    render(view: "short-index", model: [trainingList: section.trainings])
```

[null,null,null,null,null,null]

```
    respond section.trainings, [status: OK, view:"short-index"]
```

[]

it seems that trainings are visible in **short-index.gson** while used *render* but are not passed further. *respond* do not pass trainings at all. what am I missing?

Comment: I tried also without dash inside gson names, but the result was the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
json tmpl.'short-training'(trainingList ?: [])
```

With

```
json tmpl.'short-training'("training", trainingList ?: [])
```

The first argument can be used to specify the model variable name

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks.